# Some text are clear and some are blurry in my 1920 × 1080 laptop - windows 10

Tags: windows-10, high-dpi

I brought brand new **Lenevo Ideapack 310** laptop yesterday.Its configuration is:

- Intel Core i5 7th generation, 2.5GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- 1TB HDD
- NVIDIA GeForce 2GB
- Full HD 1920 × 1080 monitor
- Windows 10 Pro

My problem is that, sometimes, some windows are not properly clear and some windows are perfectly clear. I have searched in Google and I found it is a windows 10 ***DPI*** problem. But I really don't know how to solve this problem. I am worried about this because this is my brand new PC. How can I solve this problem? Should I reinstall windows 10 again?

Comment: set scaling to 100% (96dpi) or wait for Creators Update in April 2017, which has DPI scaling improvement for GDI programs

Comment: @magicandre1981 How can i set 100% scaling and 96dpi?

Comment: I posted an answer with the steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Full HD displays in laptops/notebooks, Windows 8/10 use DPI scaling of 125% by default. And this can cause some blurry texts for applciation that are not DPIaware.

Do a rightclick on the [desktop and select Display settings](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-dpi-scaling-level-displays-change-windows-10-a.html#option1).

[image]

Under `Change the size of text, apps, and other items`, select the DPI percentage of 100%.

[image]

If you run not DPIaware software, Windows will tell you a warning, that you have to log off. do this and logon again. Now you use 100% and the blurriness should be gone, but the text is smaller.

Comment: Yes its ok. But text is smaller than previous.Have any solution of it?

Comment: as I said this happens. you need to decide if you want clear or larger text. For me 100% on my Laptop is better, because I have more space.

Comment: Do you know this issue is fixed or not in the next version of windows? Because small text is very small to see.It gives pressure on eyes.Thanks and appreciated.

Comment: wait for the Windows 10 creators update in March/April 2017. It improve DPI scaling for Win32 desktop programs and fixes Windows inbox tools like device manager: https://twitter.com/shanselman/status/808790792374341632 https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/12/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14986-pc/